# jQuery AJAX table

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery

```
function searcha() {
        var api = "/api/search";
        string=document.getElementById("one").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: api,
            data: "&string=" +string,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tbl").empty;
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function (elem) {
                    items.push('<tr>');
                    $.each(elem, function (key,val) {
                        items.push('<td>' + val + '</td>');
                    })
                    items.push('</tr>');
                })
                $("#tbl").append(items.join());
            });
       }
```

html

```
<input id="one" type="text" name="search"><br>
<button id="bt" onclick="searcha()">Search</button>
<table id="tbl" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

ajax json data

```
[{"key":"val","key1":"val1"},{"key":"val","key1":"val1"}]
```

I want to make kind of live dynamic table, I tried this code, but it doesn't work for some reason, what have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) correctly.

*Use*

```
//empty is a function so you have to use ()                
$("#tbl").empty();

var items = [];

//First parameter is index and second parameter is value if argument is an array
$.each(data, function(indexInArray, elem) {
    items.push('<tr>');

    //You have to again use propertyName and valueOfProperty for object
    //Your mistake was that you have not used parameter
    $.each(elem, function(i, val) {
        items.push('<td>' + val + '</td>');
    })

    items.push('</tr>');
})
$("#tbl").append(items.join());
```